# File not found when is a space in a filename with FileUtils.copyURLToFile

Tags: java, java-io, fileutils

I am using FileUtils to save from internet some files like this:

```
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(
                    new URL(urlPath),
                    new File(destinationPath));
```

But when trying to download a file which has a space in the name it gives me File not found exception.
I've tried URLEncoder, but not helping, tried to replace the space with %20, but not helping me either.

Any help would be apreciated.
Thx.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead of the single instruction you are having problem with?

Comment: use double quotes on your url

Comment: The URL is [this](http://pictures.content4us.com/60px/BXL-AC40COMPIL.JPG)

Comment: Sorry, this is the right link: [http://pictures.content4us.com/60px/BXL-AC40 COMPIL.JPG](http://pictures.content4us.com/60px/BXL-AC40%20COMPIL.JPG). I could't save it with the above code. There's no need to a SSCCE code, as this one line code does everything. The above link is the urlPath and the destination can be any destination, like c:/test.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URLEncoder.encode() method to encode your file path with "Utf-8" charset

```
urlPath = URLEncoder.encode(urlPath,"UTF-8")
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(urlPath),new File(destinationPath));
```